# Optimization: Apply function to all values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a data frame of words that looks like this:
[image: Word df]

I built a function called `get_freq(word)` that takes a string and returns a list with the word and its frequency in a certain corpus ([iWeb Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org//iweb/)). This corpus is in another data frame called `df_freq`

```
def get_freq(word):
  word_freq=[]
  for i in range(len(df_freq)):
    if(df_freq.iloc[i, 0]==word):
      word_freq.append(word)
      word_freq.append(df_freq.iloc[i, 1])
      break
  return word_freq
```

This step works fine:

[image]

Now, I need to iterate through the whole data frame and apply the `get_freq()` function to every word in every cell. I would like the original words to be replaced by the list that the function returns.
I managed to do this with the following code:

```
for row in range(len(df2)):
  for col in range(len(df2.columns)):
    df2.values[row,col] = get_freq(df2.iat[row,col])
```

[image]

The problem is that this took over 5 minutes to complete. The reason for this is that I'm using a nested `for` and the function `get_freq(word)` has another `for` in it. I have tried using a `while` instead in the function, without improvement.

How can I optimize the execution time of this task? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How does this function `get_freq` work?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Comment: Looks like you are iterating over `df_freq` for every call. You can compute these frequencies before, store them in some dict and use it instead of this function.

Comment: I made `df_freq` into a dictionary and changed the function `get_freq` accordingly, and the execution time was decreased to just a couple of seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what [DataFrame.applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is for:

```
df = df.applymap(get_freq)
```

However, because this operation probably can't be vectorized, it's going to take some time any way you go about it.

Comment: this actually took much longer (11 min) for some reason